# qt dialog2 connect dialog1 to updateQtableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I tried many things and read about it all day with no real progress. Even as I typed this question, I went through all the Stack Overflow suggestions.
My goal? To have dialog2 send out a signal to dialog1 to call a function in dialog1, to load/update the QWidgetTable.
In dialog2(no Buttons), a keyPressEvent(F4), opens a file, saves the text that is in a lineEdit, to the file. After stream out is done, stream is flushed, file closed and lineEdit fields are reset so you can input more stuff if needed. All this works perfect, thanks in part to this forum.
But, being that dialog2 is nothing more than the size of a messageBox, you can still see dialog1 behind it, and the tableWidget that doesn't update itself with the stuff you just saved into the file. It just looks weird to the user.
This is where I'm at...

```
connect(this->ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),dialog1,SLOT(loadTable()));
```

(this) would be dialog2.
It doesn't compile. I know I'm missing something here. Signals and slots are relatively easy if widgets are inside their own "form"/"window".

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
    Dialog1::Dialog1(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog1)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);//Frameless
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Move the dialog away from the center
    this->setGeometry(0,0,this->width(),this->height());
    //Put the dialog in the screen center
    const QRect screen = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
    this->move( screen.center() - this->rect().center() );
    loadTable();

}



Dialog2::Dialog2(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog2)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);//Frameless
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Move the dialog away from the center
    this->setGeometry(0,0,this->width(),this->height());
    //Put the dialog in the screen center
    const QRect screen = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
    this->move( screen.center() - this->rect().center() ); 
   connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),&Dialog1,SLOT(loadTable()));
}
```

I don't get it.

Comment: You say it doesn't compile - can you let us know what error the compiler gives you?

Comment: if dialog1 is not a pointer, add & operator before it.
connect(this->ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),&dialog1,SLOT(loadTable()));
or
connect(this->ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), ui->dialog1,SLOT(loadTable()));

Comment: Here is the error: C:\...\...\...\dialog2.cpp:29: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token for first suggestion.

Comment: For the second suggestion, still error,,,,,,,C:\...\...\...\dialog2.cpp:29: error: 'class Ui::Dialog2' has no member named 'Dialog1'

Comment: Show more code. How is `dialog1` declared?

Comment: Agreed - we need to see your code; your compiler error means there is a problem on line 29 of dialog2.cpp, we need to know what that line is

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here :

```
connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),&Dialog1,SLOT(loadTable()));
```

You don't have Dialog1 instance. If the Dialog1 is appear first, so you need to pass your Dialog1 instance to your Dialog2, and you will able to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this in your case.

First in `Dialog2` i would create a signal. I'm going to call this signal `dataChanged`. After the saving is done, I would emit this signal:

*dialog2.h*

```
class Dialog2 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
signals:
    void dataChanged();
    ...
};
```

*dialog2.cpp:*

```
void Dialog2::save()
{
    // your save functionality...
    emit dataChanged();
}
```

Now I don't know where you create the instances of your `Dialog1` and `Dialog2` classes, but this is how you would connect the signals if the two instances are created in the same class:

```
class SomeClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
public:
    void someFunction();

private:
    Dialog1 *dialog1;
    Dialog2 *dialog2;
}
```

-

```
void SomeClass::someFunction()
{
    dialog1 = new QDialog(this);
    dialog2 = new QDialog(this);

    connect(dialog2, &Dialog2::dataChanged, dialog1, &Dialog1::loadTable);
}
```